# Performance of one big Select vs several chained selects

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

as in the question I wonder if it is better performance wise to make one big Select on a list or to make several small chained selects.

The second option for sure will be more readable as code is beaten down to smaller meaningfull parts. But the questions is, will it cost me performance?

Comment: Profile it, perhaps? But in general, assuming your operations are not too costly, iterating once will be more efficient. If whatever you're doing dwarfs the cost of the iteration, then you won't see much of a difference.

Comment: @fubo, it's tagged [collections], though, so I'd assume no database involved.

Comment: have you looked at the IL code? I imagine it will try to turn your linked wheres into a single predicate. but as soon as we start worrying about compiler optimisations its time to stop worrying

Comment: Myabe just a quick example of what you mean?

Comment: One big `Select` should be more efficient, but the difference will be unmeasurable unless you are talking about huge amounts of data.

Comment: @Magnus as requested example below:
List<int> list = new List<int>([ ... lots of data ])
list.Select< int, objectA > ( x => makeObjectAfromInt(x) )
     .Select<ObjectA, objectB>(x => x.makeObjectBfromA)

The thing is I data and need to transform it several times I can make it in one chain in one select, like makeObjectAfromInt().makeObjectBfromA(). ...
Or put each one in seperate select. 
Does it affect perfomance then?

Comment: @Joey yes no database involved thats why I did not put linq, I think its not exactly linq but generics collections what question is about

Comment: Why are you using explicit types with `Select`? That should never be necessary. As I said, chaining `Select` will be slightly less efficient, as each `Select` involves a method call with parameter passing.